# Secured connection to Data sources in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, authentication, pyspark

Generally we provide user credentials including passwords while connecting and reading data from data sources like Oracle.

But, this is not a best practice i believe, because in this case passwords are exposed to users and becomes vulnerable.
So, How to protect sensitive information like passwords in such cases by using any encryption methods or connection properties file.

It would be great if any standard practices are shared.

Current Method which exposes passwords:

```
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver") \
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .load()
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is quite popular, we should protect sensitive information and shouldn't hard coded it as well.

The general idea is to encrypt password and we will pass encrypted string as spark job parameter. Inside spark job we will decrypt this to to get to concrete password

Example

```
encrypted_password = sys.args[1]

jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver") \
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", decrypt_password(encrypted_password)) \
    .load()
```

And finally about how to encrypt it, it depends your implementation. In my company we use EMR to run Spark job so it makes sense to use KMS to encrypt and decrypt password.

Comment: Thanks for thought @Duy Nguyen Hoang, but here problem is you still have password open in arguments sys.args[1] . What if we are not using EMR like cloud service and running spark on diff Hadoop cluster.

Comment: As you are not using EMR, and you don't prefer to use KMS. I would suggest you to use ssh encryption, you can prefer to https://superuser.com/questions/20549/how-can-i-encrypt-a-string-in-the-shell for some information. You encrypt your password by using ssh key and inside your server, you can decrypt it. And only your server can decrypt it. I hope there is better solution but ssh encryption is the best one I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate. I will surely try this one and update accordingly.